# Does Clonezilla only copy a partition or can it also copy an entire disk?

Tags: partitioning, clonezilla, cloning

I'm planning to upgrade my disk to SSD, but my Linux is installed in a 1 TB hard disk, so I have to migrate/clone it.

I've seen YouTube videos of how to use Clonezilla, but in most of them
they only copy the LVM partition and not the `boot/efi` parts. I am on a laptop, so I have to choose the EFI in the BIOS manually. In the videos, when they select local source and destination, I'm not sure if they are choosing disks or partitions.

Here is my partitions setup:

[image: gparted screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clonezilla can copy both.

> Disk mode
>
> In disk mode, Clonezilla handles the whole disk, ie, all partitions at once. The MBR is copied as well.
> By default, you get an identical set of partitions on the target as they were on the source. There's an option at restore time (-k1) that allows for proportional restoration, thus enlarging the items proportionally to the size of the target drive.
>
> Partition mode
>
> In partition mode, Clonezilla handles partition(s) individually, without any disk notion. You may save any number of partitions from the source and restore only the needed one(s).

It is asked here:

[image]

Comment: Note: you don't have to copy disk-to-disk to clone a whole disk. You can create an image of the whole disk as well (like for a backup).